# How can I set up Scala-IDE to add a blank line when I start a multiline code block?

Tags: scala, scala-ide

These are the typing steps one has to take when creating a new code block in Scala-IDE. The pipe character represents the cursor:

```
def test(x: Int): Int = |
```

If you start block by typing `{`, the IDE will automatically add the closing brace and put the cursor in the middle:

```
def test(x: Int): Int = {|}
```

Hit return to start a multiline block:

```
def test(x: Int): Int = {
    |}
```

Hit return again to create a black line:

```
def test(x: Int): Int = {

    |}
```

Use arrow-up to get the cursor back to the previous line:

```
def test(x: Int): Int = {
    |
    }
```

How can you avoid the last two keystrokes, but still end up with my cursor on a blank line between the opening and closing brace? I tried, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> but no such luck.

I use a [Microsoft Arc keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/arc-keyboard/J5D-00001). In my opinion, it's the world's greatest keyboard for typing, but unfortunately also the world's worst keyboard for using arrow keys, which is why I dearly avoid using arrow keys where possible. May the guy who invented the multi-function rocker arrow key on the Arc get a cramp in his little finger every time I have to use the confounded key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in the editor (yet), but it would be a welcome addition. The best thing about it is to [file a ticket](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets).

Comment: Done, thanks (https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets/1001382#/activity/ticket:)